# What are the most popular email servers for custom domains (i.e. godaddy = secureserver.net

Tags: email, email-server, imap

I've been working on an application that will automatically detect your mail server (i.e. imap.gmail.com ) from your email address - this is working with most domain mailservers - (i.e. mail.domain.com, imap.domain.com), but I'm at the point where I need to start looking for the possibilities for mail servers that aren't associated with the domain name - so I'm looking at the godaddy's and 1and1.com's of the world.  I haven't been able to find a website with a list or table of the most popular mailservers for custom domains.

I'm looking for a table with the name of a website & the mail server.

For example:  Godaddy.com - imap.secureserver.net OR pop.secureserver.net

Comment: The reason there is no such list is because these things change constantly. Having a static list is pointless. Also, you mention servers like imap.domain.com which makes me wonder, which mail server? Maybe imap.domain.com is their pop/imap server but that doesn't mean it is the server they receive mail on (that would be listed in their mx records) nor does it mean it is the server they send their mail out of (which no doubt has an A record but otherwise you don't know for sure.

Comment: This doesn't need to be 100%, it just needs to help me go from 70% email/password accept rate to somewhere around 95% - the top 5-10 would probably help get me there.  There's always the possibility we can't find the correct mail/server, that's why we leave open the option of asking users if we can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The package 'postgrey' on Linux has an old list that's somewhat applicable under its whitelist configuration files but scripting to pull MX entries from the DNS for the popular providers or largest mail hosts is going to be easier and more accurate.